# Change styles while debugging React-Native

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, react-native

Is there a way to directly manipulate styles in the chrome dev tools while debugging in React-Native like there is for manipulating the styles of a webpage (like below)?

[image: Dev Tools Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, given the fact, that style is just a property in react-native and you can edit props on the fly with React chrome extension, it should be possible. Should, because I've had hard time making it work, maybe you'll have a better luck :) However I've seen it work in some video...

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger

Go to debugger integration and look for elemental inspector, and there i believe you can change style in runtime.